# Do holonomic physical systems really exist?

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, faster-than-light, causality, constrained-dynamics

According to Wikipedia on ‘Holonomic Constraints’:

> “In classical mechanics a system may be defined as holonomic if **all constraints** of the system are holonomic. (...) a holonomic constraint depends only on the coordinates ‘of position’ and maybe time $t$. It does not depend on the velocities or any higher-order derivative with respect to $t$. A constraint that cannot be expressed in the form shown above is a **nonholonomic constraint**.”

We know from special relativity that nothing can exceed the speed of light, therefore every physical system has a “natural” nonholonomic constraint (on the velocities). Does it mean that holonomic systems actually do not exist in reality, being those considered by classical mechanics and dynamical systems only approximations?

Comment: The speed of light limit doesn't have to be enforced as a constraint, it follows automatically from the equations of motion.

Comment: When I saw the headline question and the tags, I thought this was going to be a question about how infinitely rigid rods are unrealistic.

Comment: So, mathematically saying the speed of light is not a constraint? Only physically. It comes naturally in order to validate causality. Is it correct?